# Extracging fields in binary file

Tags: php, binary, hex

I need to extract values from a binary file. when I open it in hexadecimal reader (010 editor) i could see all the values (100) in hexadecimal format with different lengths.
My questions are
1. I don't see any delimiter when open this file in 010 editor. Could delimiter exist in this file even though i can not see?
2. What is the best way to extract each value by coding in php?

Thanks

Comment: If it's a binary file, then you probably want to locate some documentation about the format... but without knowing what type of binary file, we can't answer that for you

Comment: no document available. but I have utility to decode the file. I could see and identify all the fields. there are millions of records which i need to extract fields. simply i need how to extract byte 1 and 2, 3 to 6, 7to 9 etc.

Comment: Then look at substringing the bytes you need, and then using unpack